# How to find incomplete data in json file with python

Tags: python, json

I'm doing an online weather web app, where I want to search for a city name and it will come up and give me the weather stats about that city or town. The problem I have, is that from a free api I'm using, I got about 201 000 names and stats about towns, it's just a project and until now I was using a free postgreSQL on heroku, with 10000 lines max. And I just don't want to pay for it.
Now for my problem, I want my search to be able to get a list of names from the json file, when I give them for example half of the names. To clarify, when I search for "New" I want the result to be "New York, New Hampshire, New ..." here is what my json file looks like.

```
[
  {
    "id": 833,
    "name": "Ḩeşār-e Sefīd",
    "state": "",
    "country": "IR",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 47.159401,
      "lat": 34.330502
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2960,
    "name": "‘Ayn Ḩalāqīm",
    "state": "",
    "country": "SY",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 36.321911,
      "lat": 34.940079
    }
  }
]
```

SOLVED:

```
data = json.loads(f.read())
partsearch = [town for town in data if town["name"].lower().__contains__(search) or town["name"].lower().startswith(search) or town["name"] == search or town["name"].lower() == search]
```

Comment: Google in-memory db with python, and dump everything in there, the good part will be that u might not need to change any sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension for that selection

```
import json

data = json.loads("""[{"id": 833, "name": "Ḩeşār-e Sefīd", "state": "", "country": "IR", "coord": {"lon": 47.159401, "lat": 34.330502}}, {"id": 2960, "name": "‘Ayn Ḩalāqīm", "state": "", "country": "SY", "coord": {"lon": 36.321911, "lat": 34.940079}}]""")

search = "New"
filtered = [town for town in data if town["name"].startswith(search)]
```